# How to prevent a sort on a groupby.applyInPandas using hash partitioning on the upstream dataset?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, partitioning, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

In my main transform, I'm running an algorithm by doing a `groupby` and then `applyInPandas` in Foundry. The build takes very long, and one idea is to organize the files to prevent shuffle reads and sorting, using Hash partitioning/bucketing.

For a mcve, I have the following dataset:

```
def example_df():
    return spark.createDataFrame(
    [("1","2", 1.0), ("1","3", 2.0), ("2","4", 3.0), ("2","5", 5.0), ("2","2", 10.0)],
    ("id_1","id_2", "v"))
```

[image]

The transform I want to apply is:

```
def df1(example_df):
    def subtract_mean(pdf):
        v = pdf.v
        return pdf.assign(v=v - v.mean())

    return example_df.groupby("id_1","id_2").applyInPandas(subtract_mean, schema="id_1 string, id_2 string, v double")
```

When I look at the original query plan, with no partitioning, it looks like the following:

[image]

Physical Plan:

```
Execute FoundrySaveDatasetCommand `ri.foundry.main.transaction.00000059-eb1b-61f4-bdb8-a030ac6baf0a@master`.`ri.foundry.main.dataset.eb664037-fcae-4ce2-b92b-bd103cd504b3`, ErrorIfExists, [id_1, id_2, v], ComputedStatsServiceV2Blocking{_endpointChannelFactory=DialogueChannel@3127a629{channelName=dialogue-nonreloading-ComputedStatsServiceV2Blocking, delegate=com.palantir.dialogue.core.DialogueChannel$Builder$$Lambda$713/0x0000000800807c40@70f51090}, runtime=com.palantir.conjure.java.dialogue.serde.DefaultConjureRuntime@6c67a62a}, com.palantir.foundry.spark.catalog.caching.CachingSchemaService@7d881feb, com.palantir.foundry.spark.catalog.caching.CachingMetadataService@57a1ef9e, com.palantir.foundry.spark.catalog.FoundrySparkResolver@4d38f6f5, com.palantir.foundry.spark.auth.DefaultFoundrySparkAuthSupplier@21103ab4
+- AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=true
   +- == Final Plan ==
      *(3) BasicStats `ri.foundry.main.transaction.00000059-eb1b-61f4-bdb8-a030ac6baf0a@master`.`ri.foundry.main.dataset.eb664037-fcae-4ce2-b92b-bd103cd504b3`
      +- FlatMapGroupsInPandas [id_1#487, id_2#488], subtract_mean(id_1#487, id_2#488, v#489), [id_1#497, id_2#498, v#499]
         +- *(2) Sort [id_1#487 ASC NULLS FIRST, id_2#488 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
            +- AQEShuffleRead coalesced
               +- ShuffleQueryStage 0
                  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id_1#487, id_2#488, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#324]
                     +- *(1) Project [id_1#487, id_2#488, id_1#487, id_2#488, v#489]
                        +- *(1) ColumnarToRow
                           +- FileScan parquet !ri.foundry.main.transaction.00000059-eb12-f234-b25f-57e967fbc68e:ri.foundry.main.transaction.00000059-eb12-f234-b25f-57e967fbc68e@00000003-99f9-3d2d-814f-e4db9c920cc2:master.ri.foundry.main.dataset.237cddc5-0835-425c-bfbe-e62c51779dc2[id_1#487,id_2#488,v#489] Batched: true, BucketedScan: false, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[sparkfoundry:///datasets/..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<id_1:string,id_2:string,v:double>, ScanMode: RegularMode
```

My goal is to prevent the need for the `Sort`, `Shuffle` (read and query) and `Exchange` from the query plan.

To achieve this, I hash partition an intermediate dataset, bucketing by the id columns I'm going to groupBy later:

```
def example_df_bucketed(example_df):
    example_df = example_df.repartition(2,"id_1","id_2")
    output = Transforms.get_output()
    output_fs = output.filesystem()
    output.write_dataframe(example_df,bucket_cols=["id_1","id_2"], sort_by=["id_1","id_2"], bucket_count=2)
```

I try and run the same logic, this time with the bucketed dataset as the input

```
def df2(example_df_bucketed):
    def subtract_mean(pdf):
        # pdf is a pandas.DataFrame
        v = pdf.v
        return pdf.assign(v=v - v.mean())

    return example_df_bucketed.groupby("id_1","id_2").applyInPandas(subtract_mean, schema="id_1 string, id_2 string, v double")
```

This results in the query plan not having a shuffle (hash partition), but it is still sorting.

[image]

Physical Plan:

```
Execute FoundrySaveDatasetCommand `ri.foundry.main.transaction.00000059-ec4c-26f7-a058-98be3f26018c@master`.`ri.foundry.main.dataset.02990b20-95f2-4605-9e7c-578ba071535d`, ErrorIfExists, [id_1, id_2, v], ComputedStatsServiceV2Blocking{_endpointChannelFactory=DialogueChannel@3127a629{channelName=dialogue-nonreloading-ComputedStatsServiceV2Blocking, delegate=com.palantir.dialogue.core.DialogueChannel$Builder$$Lambda$713/0x0000000800807c40@70f51090}, runtime=com.palantir.conjure.java.dialogue.serde.DefaultConjureRuntime@6c67a62a}, com.palantir.foundry.spark.catalog.caching.CachingSchemaService@3db2ee77, com.palantir.foundry.spark.catalog.caching.CachingMetadataService@8086bb, com.palantir.foundry.spark.catalog.FoundrySparkResolver@7ebc329, com.palantir.foundry.spark.auth.DefaultFoundrySparkAuthSupplier@46d15de1
+- AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=true
   +- == Final Plan ==
      *(2) BasicStats `ri.foundry.main.transaction.00000059-ec4c-26f7-a058-98be3f26018c@master`.`ri.foundry.main.dataset.02990b20-95f2-4605-9e7c-578ba071535d`
      +- FlatMapGroupsInPandas [id_1#603, id_2#604], subtract_mean(id_1#603, id_2#604, v#605), [id_1#613, id_2#614, v#615]
         +- *(1) Sort [id_1#603 ASC NULLS FIRST, id_2#604 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
            +- *(1) Project [id_1#603, id_2#604, id_1#603, id_2#604, v#605]
               +- *(1) ColumnarToRow
                  +- FileScan parquet !ri.foundry.main.transaction.00000059-ec22-2287-a0e3-5d9c48a39a83:ri.foundry.main.transaction.00000059-ec22-2287-a0e3-5d9c48a39a83@00000003-99fc-8b63-8d17-b7e45fface86:master.ri.foundry.main.dataset.bbada128-5538-4c7f-b5ba-6d16b15da5bf[id_1#603,id_2#604,v#605] Batched: true, BucketedScan: true, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[sparkfoundry://foundry/datasets/..., PartitionFilters: [], Partitioning: hashpartitioning(id_1#603, id_2#604, 2), PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<id_1:string,id_2:string,v:double>, ScanMode: RegularMode, SelectedBucketsCount: 2 out of 2
```

Since I'm already setting the `sort_by` when I bucket upstream, why is there still a sort in the query plan?  Is there something I can do to avoid this sort?